# I have a bound ModelForm that is invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a ModelForm that links to an external database, and when you submit the form the external database gets updated. The problem comes when I check the validity of the form, it is invalid.

I have done some researching into this and found the most common problem was that the form is not bound, but when I use print(form.non_field_errors) I get:
`<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <EmailForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(subject;body;name;altsubject;utm_source;utm_content;utm_campaign)>`

models.py:

```
class MarketingEmails(models.Model):
    messageid = models.AutoField(db_column='column1', primary_key=True)
    subject = models.CharField(db_column='column2', max_length=2000)
    body = models.TextField(db_column='column3') #using a text field as there is no maximum length
    name = models.CharField(db_column='column4', max_length=25)
    altsubject = models.CharField(db_column='column5', max_length=2000)
    utm_source = models.CharField(db_column='column6', max_length=25)
    utm_content = models.CharField(db_column='column7', max_length=25)
    utm_campaign = models.CharField(db_column='column8', max_length=25)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = ''
```

forms.py:

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingEmails
        fields = ['messageid','subject','body','name','altsubject','utm_source','utm_content','utm_campaign']
```

views.py:

```
def emailinfo(request, pk):
    if request.session.has_key('shortname'):
        shortname =  request.session['shortname']
        rows = get_object_or_404(MarketingEmails, pk=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EmailForm(request.POST)
            print(form.errors)
            print(form.non_field_errors)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                print("form is valid")
                return redirect('marketingemails:emailinfo', pk = rows.messageid)

        return render(request, 'marketingemails/emailinfo.html',{'shortname': shortname, 'rows': rows})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('common:login'))
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'marketingemails'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^marketing/emails/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', marketingviews.emailinfo, name='emailinfo'),
]
```

html:

```
        <form method="POST" class="post-form" action ="">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Name</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.name }}</textarea>

        <label for="exampleTextarea">Subject</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.subject }}</textarea>

        <label for="exampleTextarea">Alternative Subject</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.altsubject }}</textarea>

        <label for="exampleTextarea">Body</label>
        <div class="ibox-content no-padding">
            <div class="summernote">
                {{ rows.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <label for="exampleTextarea">utm_source</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.utm_source }}</textarea>

        <label for="exampleTextarea">utm_content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.utm_content }}</textarea>

        <label for="exampleTextarea">utm_campaign</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="1">{{ rows.utm_campaign }}</textarea>

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: and how are you sending the form?? in the view there is nothing for the GET method? and where is the names of the input fields in your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML form doesn't name the fields so the form can't get them. You want to use the form for rendering too : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates